# How to change current category to another in wordpress

Tags: categories, plugin-contact-form-7, core

I am new to PHP. Please help me to achieve the below scenario. I am trying to achieve this from the last 3 days.

I've two categories in my WordPress dashboard named "Available (id:3)" and "Booked (id:4)". In the "available" category a few numbers are there as posts.

In each post page contact 7 form is embedded.

When I submit a "contact form 7" successfully from that post, I would like to move that current post to the "booked" category.

Please check the link and click any numbers for what I am looking for.

'Available' category: http://uei.iwu.mybluehost.me/free212/category/available/
'Booked' category:http://uei.iwu.mybluehost.me/free212/category/booked/

I tried something like below in my functions.php and not working at all.

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function ($cf7) {
    $category_id = get_cat_ID('available');
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    wp_remove_object_terms( $post_id, 'available', 'category');
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'booked', 'category');
});
```

Comment: Does the function run? Are you sure that when it runs `get_the_ID()` gives a valid post ID ?

Comment: No. its not running. As I told I am new to php and wordpress. So I am trying something and nothing works.

Comment: Well by 'run' I mean does the code execute. Perhaps it doesn't execute, or it does execute but doesn't work. First work out if it's executed or not, and if it's executed, then figure out why it's not working. As an easy fix you should try replacing `$post_id = get_the_ID()` with `global $post; $post_id = $post->ID;`

Comment: I tried with global post also. But not executing the code. I think my code is not correct